# How to check that element exists on page

Tags: android, ruby, calabash

How I should check, that element is exists on page in Calabash-Android?

I try test app with one activity, but many layout. How I should do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify the item uniquely using accessibilityLabels. And if you know the accessibilityLabel of the item you try to find. 
you can easily find it like this

think you have a label which accessibilityLabel is "phoneNumlabel"

`element_exists("textview marked:'#{phoneNumlabel}'")`

this will returns a boolean value. Also you can use wait function to wait until that a component appears with a time out. like this

`wait_for_elements_exist(["android.widget.ProgressBar"], :timeout => 30)`

Get a help with predefined steps http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.com/2013/10/calabash-android-predefines-steps.html